# How do I connect c# console to database?

Tags: c#, authentication

I am making a c# console application and would like to add a login system.

I have this code already:

```
Start:
        Console.Clear();
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Username.");
        string strUsername = Console.ReadLine();
        string strTUsername = "Test";

        if (strUsername == strTUsername)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Password");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            string strPassword = Console.ReadLine();
            string strTPassword = "Test";
            if ( strPassword == strTPassword)
            {
                Console.Write("Logging in.");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            else
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("The password you entered is wrong.");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                goto Start;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("The username you entered is wrong.");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            goto Start;
        }
```

I would like to make it allow multiple username and passwords that you can enter that will work.

So far it just accepts the username and password 'Test' but I would like to link it to another file filled with username and passwords that I can use instead of just 'Test'.

Any help you can give me or provide is useful thanks!

Comment: Whatever really, if I can enter multiple usernames and passwords specific for different profiles then that will work for me.

Comment: You're going to get crucified for your use of `goto`.

Comment: What else can I use? lol

Comment: @Drips use a while or for loop and get out of it when the user gives correct password. :)

Comment: Just a tip, I would not store passwords in clear text in any external db/file. Instead do some hashing and test the user enter password against that. Also do not have any clear text password in your code either like you do above, you can easily see source code of .net applications

Answer (score 2):

You have two ways of doing it:

```
1: Database to store username and password
2: Save the username and password in file in a uniform format(like comma,tab separated)
```

**1:Database**

```
->Select a database to use
->create a table with columns such as username and password
->connect to database from your app
->get username from console and compare it with the rows of database and check if the password given is correct.
```

**2:File**

```
->Save a file with username and password with a certain format(comma,space or tab separated)
->Import those from the file to a Dictionay<users>.
->compare the entered password and user name with the dictionary items.
```

You can use encryption to make the file or database more secure.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<User> usersList = new List<User>();
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("users.txt");
            foreach ( var line in lines)
            {
                User user = new User();
                user.user = line.Split(' ')[0];
                user.password = line.Split(' ')[1];
                usersList.Add(user);
            }
            foreach (var item in usersList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.user);
                Console.WriteLine(item.password);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }



}
public class User
{
   public string user { get; set; }
   public  string password { get; set; }
}
```

In this I have added a simple code to read a space separated password file and use it as per your requirement. For a more secure way you can encript the file. Thank you

Comment: What can I use to make the database? How can I connect the console to the database?

Comment: which database you want to use ?

Comment: @soumyasambitKunda Anything that I can use that will work, what are my options?

Comment: if you want to save the password in a local system in a secure manner I will suggest to use password vault :)

Comment: @Drips If it makes sense I can post links and code for that.

Comment: It would really help if someone could provide some code used with my code to show me some examples. :)

Comment: @Drips I have edited my code with some code check it and let me know it helped you..